# If 71:64 then 92:?

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

This question was in the logical reasoning section of an exam I had recently appeared in. I still have no clue how this is solved.

> If 71:64 then 92:?

The given options are-

> 1. 25
> 2. 32
> 3. 35
> 4. 42

Comment: 7+1+6+4=18 so 9+2+2+5=18

Comment: Some more confusion, 7,1 do not enclose any area and 6,4 both do,so 42

Comment: There is insufficient information to solve this. Multiple answers can be justified.

Comment: Yeah I agree with @Jeff Zeitlin. There doesnt seem to be much context here. Dont quite understand what the ":" means either.

Comment: @avenger12 - the normal reading of **A:B** in problems like this is "A is to B...", and this problem would be read as "71 is to 64 as 92 is to _what?_". More verbosely, "The relationship between 71 and 64 is like the relationship between 92 and _what?_".

Answer (score 4):

The logic i have found;

> all digits are different, since 35 is the only one that satisfies this condition, it is the answer under this logic :)

Since there are not many digits, numbers etc, one may find other type of answers but i believe this is the best answer!

Answer (score 2):

the logic i have found:

> 71 (odd,odd) : 64(even,even) ==> 92 (odd,even) : **25** (even, odd)
> -Opposites-

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer could be

> 32

The logic is -

> 71:64 both of these numbers are divisible by (and hence instantly reduce to a further non-reducible fractions) 7, when 1 is subtracted from each (so that the new set of numbers become 70:63 or 10:9).

In this case

> 92:32 exhibits the same property, when 2 is subtracted from both the numbers to arrive at 90:30 or 3:1